# multilingual wordpress outside wp-content

Tags: php, wordpress, web, multilingual, wpml

So, i just create a folder outside wp-content and i script pages with php language on my custom folder. And i want to translate all my pages that i have made when i upload to wordpress. The directory just like this :

> wordpress folder
>
> - wp_admin
> - wp_content
> - wp_include
> - my_custom_folder_with_php_pages_inside

can i use plugin to translate the php file inside my custom folder?
any advice for me?

thanks in advance anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

WordPress is completely unaware of your PHP scripts since none of its PHP code is including them.

If you want to use WPML to translate "pages", you need to first create them from within WordPress, e.g. from the administration dashboard:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/pages/

You can then use WPML translation flow to translate these pages:

https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/

I'm not sure what you mean by *"i want to translate all my pages that i have made when i upload to wordpress"*, perhaps I'm not understanding completely your process. You may want to edit your question to clarify this part.